# Как отловить событие "доскроллили до самого низа страницы"?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, прокрутка, события, property

Как сделать, когда доскролишь до самого низа страницы, чтобы поменялся background, как отловить тот момент, когда уже уперлись в самый низ страницы ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы так

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
    $("html,body").css({
      "background": "pink"
    })
  } else {
    $("html,body").css({
      "background": "blue"
    })
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 200vh;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: слушай, а как у нас получается $(window).scrollTop() , когда он упирается в низ страницы, при такий вычислениях $(document).height() - $(window).height()?

Comment: @bogdaryan, `$(document).height()` - это полная высота, `$(window).height()` - это высота видимой части окна. Если  их разница равна `$(window).scrollTop()` - тому что уже прокручено, то ниже прокрутить уже нельзя

Comment: Всё, понял, спасибо